# How can I get pyplot images to show on a console app?

Tags: python, image, console, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an image using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`.  However, when I run the program from my console, it doesn't display anything?

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

myimage = gen_image()

matplotlib.pyplot.gray()
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(results)
```

But this shows nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to call the `show` function to actually display anything, like

```
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Unfortunately the matplotlib documentation seems to be currently broken, so I can't provide a link.

Note that for interactive plotting one typically uses IPython, which has special support for matplotlib.

By the way, you can do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

to make the typing less tedious (this is pretty much the official standard way).